# MBProgressHUD not displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

Before I move to my next view controller I'd like to display MBProcessHUD for 5 seconds. This is the current implementation

```
-(void)login
{
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [hud setDimBackground:YES];
    [hud setOpacity:0.5f];
    [hud show:YES];
    [hud hide:YES afterDelay:10.0];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *obj=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"accountTableViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
}
```

Unfortunately the HUD does not display at all.

Comment: thats because your push the new view controller and the hud is displayed on the previous view controller.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, what would you suggest to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
-(void)login
{
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [hud setDimBackground:YES];
    [hud setOpacity:0.5f];
    [hud show:YES];
    [hud hide:YES afterDelay:5.0];

    [self performSelector:@selector(pushView) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
}

- (void) pushView {

   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   UITabBarController *obj=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"accountTableViewController"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];

}
```

Although this should work, I assume you will be doing some processing to try and log a user in ? In which case you can use:

```
    [hud showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^{
       //Log the user in:
    } completionBlock:^{
      //Then push the new view here, the hud will automatically dismiss. 
    }];
```

Comment: thank you, the latter worked exactly how I wanted to.